# Differences between KOH and phosphorus pentoxide as drying agents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

The most common drying agent I encountered when using a vacuum dessicator was phosphorus pentoxide in the form of Sicapent. But I've recently encountered people using KOH as a cheaper alternative (in a practical course for students, where such costs are amplified due to the high number of students).

What are the differences between KOH and phosphorus pentoxide as a general purpose drying agents to remove water? Is there a difference in effectiveness? Are there classes of substances where you can't use one of those drying agents?

Comment: short answer: KOH will cheaply dry alcohols, KBr pellets,  and most organic liquids.  Phosphorous pentoxide—a bit more expensive—will dry sulfuric acid into sulfur trioxide and anything else it contacts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found [this page](http://www.erowid.org/archive/rhodium/chemistry/equipment/dryingchemicals.html), which recreates information from *Purification of Laboratory Chemicals*, by Perrin and Armarego. It provides a qualitative ranking of drying agents, listing phosphorous pentoxide higher than KOH. The two drying agents work by different means:

**KOH**

Anhydrous KOH is hygroscopic. It absorbs water from the atmosphere. It much better at doing so than more common hygroscopic drying agents like calcium chloride or calcium sulfate (drierite). A pellet of KOH left out in a beaker or dish open to the air will have absorbed so much water vapor within an hour that it will now be a solution of KOH (that will continue to be hygroscopic, at least until the solution is 50% water). Calcium chloride and calcium sulfate only continue to absorb water until they reach their maximum hydration.

**P<sub>4</sub>O<sub>10</sub>**

Phosphorous pentoxide (really P<sub>4</sub>O<sub>10</sub>) is an anhydride of phosphoric acid. Phosphorous pentoxide reacts with water to form phosphoric acid: 
$$\ce{P4O10 + 6H2O -> 4H3PO4}$$
Phosphoric acid is also hygroscopic and absorbs water to form a solution.

Since P<sub>4</sub>O<sub>10</sub> is water reactive it is more difficult and dangerous to handle, especially for large groups of students. I might not use P<sub>4</sub>O<sub>10</sub> if the substance being dried is very acid sensitive. Eventually, the vacuum will start volatilizing the acid. I might not use KOH for compounds that are incredibly base sensitive, although it is unlikely that KOH will sublime. In an undergraduate lab with multiple students, KOH should be fine if you want to save money and hassle.

Comment: This answer is exactly right and deserves to be marked as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Usage of drying agent is ruled by four factors: cost, effectiveness, reactions it can provoke in substance being dried, level of discomfort in working process.

$\ce{P2O5}$ is much more effective, $\ce{KOH}$ is cheaper and easier to handle. $\ce{P2O5}$ is also acidic and $\ce{KOH}$ is basic. There are substances that die in acidic environment (acetales) and those that die in basic environment (halogen-anhydrides).

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{P2O5}$ is an acidic oxide while $\ce{KOH}$ is a base. So if you want to dry substances which are acidic you must use $\ce{P2O5}$, while if you want to dry a substance that is basic in nature, you have to use $\ce{KOH}$.